# input очищение при вводе текста и обязательное заполнение

Tags: input, required

Есть поле ввода номера телефона,нужно чтобы:

1. при нажатии очищается поле ввода текста
2. если поле ввода пусто, то при нажатии на кнопку выводится сообщение "заполните поле"

Работает `required` отслеживающий ввод текста, добавляла скрипты для очищения, перестает `required` работать.

```
Напишите телефон    
<input name="Телефон" type="text" class="pole" required placeholder="+780080080" />
Отправить 
<input class="tab_zakaz_knopka" name="_submit_" type="image" src="img/zakazat.jpg"  onfocus="if(value=='+780080080'){value=''}" onblur="if(value=='') { value='+780080080' }"/>
```

Если добавить в input:

```
onfocus="if(value=='+780080080') {value=''}"
onblur="if(value=='') {value='+780080080'}"
```

Comment: Добавьте код скриптов, потому что из вопроса не понятно, что за скрипты и на что они влияют.

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin посмотрите, добавила

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
//когда поле в фокусе
 $('.pole').focus(function(){
      //убераем подсказку формата номера и обнуляем значение value
      $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
      $(this).val('');
      
      //когда инпут теряет фокус
      $(this).blur(function(){
      //если в инпуте пусто то прописываем подсказку формата номера
        if($(this).val()==''){
          $(this).attr('placeholder', '+780080080');
        }
      });    
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
Напишите телефон    
<input name="Телефон" type="text" class="pole" required placeholder="+780080080" />
Отправить 
<input class="tab_zakaz_knopka" name="_submit_" type="image" src="img/zakazat.jpg"  />
</form>
```

Comment: благодарю!то что надо!